# Webhook GitHub jenkins pipeline not triggered, but jenkins freestyle project not problem

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Halo, i'm using jenkins pipeline, but github webhook doesn't trigger. if using jenkins freestyle project webhook github to trigger. is there something wrong?

Thank u guys

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yeah, i must **Build Now** manually at first job created.